# Half of Matrix Size Missing

Tags: python

I wanted to ask why is it that some of my matrices in Python are missing a size value? The matrices/arrays that re defined show the numbers in them, but the size is missing and it is throwing me other errors because of it. Why is the variable explorer missing this info or why is it that Python can't identify the size?

[Example of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rx72.jpg)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import random
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import random as rand

ParticleCount = 100 ## of particles to generate energies for energy generation
binsize = 15 #Determines bin size for historgram of electron energies
S1 = 0.0200001 #Specify minimum radius particles may be generated
S2 = 0.0200002 #Specify maximum radius particles may be generated
phi1 = -90
phi2 = 90
phi1rad = phi1*(np.pi/180)
phi2rad = phi2*(np.pi/180)

#Generate random positions for each particle between s1 and s2
#ICPositions = np.array([])
ICPositions = np.empty([3,ParticleCount],dtype = float)
SphPositions = np.empty([3,ParticleCount],dtype = float)
for i in range(0,ParticleCount):
    #In Spherical: Generates random position with boundaries of: S1<r<S2
    rrand = (S2 - S1)*rand.uniform(0,1) + S1 #Random # generation for component x between s1 and s2
    thetarand = (2*np.pi)*rand.uniform(0,1) #Random # generation for component y between s1 and s2
    phirand = np.arcsin((np.sin(phi2rad) - np.sin(phi1rad))*rand.uniform(0,1) + np.sin(phi1rad))
    xrand = RStart*np.sin(phirand)*np.cos(thetarand)
    yrand = RStart*np.sin(phirand)*np.sin(thetarand)
    zrand = RStart*np.cos(phirand)
    sphArray = np.array([RStart,thetarand,phirand])
    randArray = np.array([xrand,yrand,zrand])
    randArray = np.array(randArray,dtype = float)
    if ICPositions.size == 0:
        ICPositions = np.array([randArray])
    else:
        ICPositions = np.append(ICPositions,[randArray],axis = 0)

print(ICPositions)
```

Comment: In `for i in range(0,ParticleCount):`, you seem overwriting sphArray and randArray each loop. Make empty array  first and append for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up your code a little...

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand

ParticleCount = 100 # of particles to generate energies for energy generation
S1 = 0.0200001 #Specify minimum radius particles may be generated
S2 = 0.0200002 #Specify maximum radius particles may be generated
phi1 = -20
phi2 = 20
phi1rad = phi1*(np.pi/180)
phi2rad = phi2*(np.pi/180)

#Generate random positions for each particle between s1 and s2
sphArray = np.zeros([3,ParticleCount])
randArray = np.empty([3,ParticleCount])
for i in range(0,ParticleCount):
    #In Spherical: Generates random position with boundaries of: S1<r<S2
    RStart = (S2 - S1)*rand.uniform(0,1) + S1 #Random # generation for component x between s1 and s2
    thetarand = (2*np.pi)*rand.uniform(0,1) #Random # generation for component y between s1 and s2
    phirand = np.arcsin((np.sin(phi2rad) - np.sin(phi1rad))*rand.uniform(0,1) + np.sin(phi1rad))
    xrand = RStart*np.cos(phirand)*np.cos(thetarand)
    yrand = RStart*np.cos(phirand)*np.sin(thetarand)
    zrand = RStart*np.sin(phirand)
    sphArray[:,i] = [RStart,thetarand,phirand]
    randArray[:,i] = [xrand,yrand,zrand]
```

Some hints:

- Stackoverflow is not meant to post messy code hoping that somebody will clean it up for you.
- If you define phi from -90 to 90 you need to adapt the conversion from spherical to Cartesian coordinates accordingly.
- No need to define and append arrays over and over. You know its size beforehand. Better create it and fill it while looping.
- There is no information missing. You have defined SphPositions and randArray/SphArray differently. The former is a 2D array, the latter are 1D.

Comment: Thank you the answer and hints but I would like to address the bullet points. For the first point; I am new to Python and the coding world in general. I only started two months ago in Python and I am completely self taught. I do not use these forums "hoping that somebody will clean" up my code for me. The syntax I use is based on my limited knowledge of coding and so I may be employing a method that isn't as ideal as someone more experienced may know of. For the second bullet point, I will look into that.

Comment: For the third bullet point; I tried the same method you did originally (w/o appending anything) and for some reason it was throwing me an error which is why I chose to use the if-else statement. Fourth point; There is size information missing. The array size is a (3,1) not a (3,nothing). It is a defined vector so it makes no sense me that Spyder is saying there is no size to it half of it.

Comment: I eventually figured out how to make it see a (3,1) and that was to just add an additional pair of brackets within the array definition. Still do not see why it needs that.